# Why the $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{2\arctan(x)}{\pi}\right)^x$ is not equal to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, trigonometry

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413008/lim-x-to-infty-left-frac2-arctanx-pi-rightx?rq=1) on the site. It asked to evaluate:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{2\arctan(x)}{\pi}\right)^x.$$

Although the answer is $e^{\tfrac{-2}{\pi}}$, I don't completely understand why the limit is not equal to zero. I think it should be zero because as $x\to\frac{\pi}2^-$, $\tan x\to+\infty$. Hence we have the limit of $(\frac2{\pi}\times{(\frac{\pi}2}^-))^{\infty}$. and it should be zero (for example the value of $0.99999^{1000000}$ is very close to zero.

Comment: $0.99999^{1000000}$ may be close to $0$, but $0.9999999^{1000000}$ is close to $1$. A limit that looks like $(1^-)^\infty$ can wind up anywhere between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result highly depends on the "speed" with which $\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x$ tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to infinity . You cannot just come up with an example like $0.99999^{1000000}$ and expect that the value has any connection with the value of the limit... If that was the case, there would be no indeterminations: every limit of the type $1^{\infty}$ would be zero.

The appropriate approximation here would be

$$
0.9999993633802277^{1000000}\approx 0.529078 \approx e^{-2/\pi}
$$

Comment: @Soheil0098 Yes, $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can not just plug the limit it, since the form you get is indeterminate: $1^{\infty}$. To show you another (very famous) example why this does not work:

Consider
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n.$$
You may recall that this limit is the defintion of $e\approx2.7$. But if we were to plug in the limit immediatly we'd get
$$(1+0)^\infty.$$
And $e\neq0$ (nor $1$ or $\infty$).

---

Same thing for
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{2\arctan(x)}{\pi}\right)^x.$$
We also have $1^\infty$, but as you said correctly it's $e^{-2/\pi}$.

---

**Addendum:** [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the link also was very useful, it changed my perspective of limits.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

> As $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-$, $\arctan x \to +\infty$

is incorrect.  You are confusing $\tan x$ and $\arctan x$.

Second, your suggestion that the indeterminate form $1^\infty \to 0$ is also incorrect.  For instance,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e,$$ in which $1 + 1/x \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.  However,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x = 1,$$ yet $1 + 1/x^2 \to 1$ also as $x \to \infty$.  And

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2} = \infty.$$  All of these are indeterminate forms of type $1^\infty$ yet they have different limits, none of which are zero.

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$\left(\frac{2\arctan x}\pi\right)^x=e^{x\log\frac{2\arctan x}x}$$

and now L'hospital

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\frac{2\arctan x}\pi}{\frac1x}\stackrel{\text{L'H}\frac00}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac1\pi\frac2{1+x^2}\frac\pi{2\arctan x}}{-\frac1{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{ x^2}{1+x^2}\cdot\frac1{\arctan x}=-1\cdot\frac1{\frac\pi2}=-\frac2\pi$$

and by continutiyt of the exponential function, the limit is $\;e^{-2/\pi}\;$